# The PHP login match of

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, authentication

I'm using the following piece of code to collect the form data and validate with the login and password, stored in the mysql table. When I try to validate using single parameter $email then the query is fetching the rowCount but when i put AND condition and try to match password as well then it does not work.. the codes are pasted below:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $pass=$_POST["pass"];
    print_r($_POST);
    include('include/conn/connection.php');
    $sql = " SELECT d_email,d_password FROM donor WHERE d_email =? AND d_password=? ";
    $result = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute(array($email,$pass));
    $row = $result->fetch();  
    $count = $result->rowCount();
```

Comment: Never store plain text passwords.

Comment: What exactly does "it does not work" mean? Are you getting an error? Not getting the expected results?

Comment: You should look into using `password_hash` and `password_verify` for storing passwords and checking.

Comment: It might not return results if those do not match. You might want to query for username only and then check if password matches with the result.

Comment: the query with the only username is fetching the row but when I put also password with AND then it does not fetch the result.